# Running Command Recursively in all Subdirectories

Tags: bash

I have a folder which contains a depth of up to 3 layers of subdirectories, with images in the deepest subdirectory (for most images, this is just one level). I want to rename these images to include the name of the directory they are in as a prefix. For this, I need to be able to run a single command for each subdirectory in this tree of subdirectories.
This is my attempt:

```
DIRS=/home/arjung2/data_256_nodir/a/*

for dir in $DIRS
do
    for f in $dir
    do
        echo "$dir" 
        echo "$f"
        echo "$dir_$f"
        mv "$f" "$dir_$f"
    done
done
```

However, the first three `echo`s prints out the same thing for each 1-level deep subdirectory (not all up to 3-level deep subdirectories as I desire), and gives me an error. An example output is the following:

```
/home/arjung2/data_256_nodir/a/airfield
/home/arjung2/data_256_nodir/a/airfield
/home/arjung2/data_256_nodir/a/airfield
mv: cannot move ‘/home/arjung2/data_256_nodir/a/airfield’ to a subdirectory of itself, ‘/home/arjung2/data_256_nodir/a/airfield/airfield’
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: what is supposed to be `$dir_$f`? Is there a variable `dir_` set? Or is it a typo and you meant to write `${dir}_$f`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all images can be identified with 'find' (e.g., by suffix), consider the following bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash

find . -type f -name '*.jpeg' -print0 | while read -d '' file ; do
    d=${file%/*};
    d1=${d##*/};
    new_file="$d/${d1}_${file##*/}"
    echo "Move: $file -> $new_file"
    mv "$file" "$new_file"
done
```

It will move a/b/c.jpeg to a/b/b_c.jpeg, for every folder/file. Adjust (or remove) the -name as needed.

Comment: The print0 is really great, but don't forget to include a '-r' in the read command. Generally you should also do mv -- "$file" "$new_file" but that can be left out here, because of find representation always starting with ./

Answer (score 1):

Say `dir` has the value `/home/arjung2/data_256_nodir/a/airfield`. In this case, the statement

```
for f in $dir
```

expands to

```
for f in /home/arjung2/data_256_nodir/a/airfield
```

which means that the inner loop will be executed exactly once, `f` taking the name `/home/arjung2/data_256_nodir/a/airfield`, which is the same as `dir`.

It would make more sense to iterate over the files within the directory:

```
for f in $dir/*
```

Comment: But the the value of `$f` will be a relative path which you can't use as the destination of the `mv` (unless `path/to/f` happens to contain the directory `path/to/f/path/to`)

Comment: Of course the destination diretory for the move needs to be fixed as well. I just wanted to focus on the first bug, i.e. why the first two variables have the same content. For insance, `$dir_$f` does not make sense (as KamilCuk pointed out already in the comment), because there is no variable named `dir_`.